# How to programmatically connect to a wifi network in android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Given that SSID and password of a wifi is known, how can I programmatically connect the android device to that wifi network in android-NDK?

Comment: [These](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference) are the available NDK APIs. If there's nothing there for connecting to a WiFi, you'll have to call the appropriate Java API  instead via JNI.

Comment: @Michael is pointing in the right direction. Its no joke to do this without APIs, so do *whatever* you have to but **use an API**. As a sidenote, i'll suggest removing either one of the c and c++ tags, and keeping the one you actually intend to program in.

Comment: OK, removed ```c``` tag but I still cant find API to deal with wifi from @Michael 's answer!